# What does the CALLBACK keyword mean in a Win-32 C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Some function calls in Win-32 C++ applications have the `CALLBACK` keyword applied to them, as in this example (taken from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modal_box)):

```
BOOL CALLBACK DeleteItemProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message,
                             WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    // ... code here ...
}
```

I see via Visual Studio that the `CALLBACK` keyword is defined (using `#define`) as `__stdcall`. The [__stdcall documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't make it much clearer (to me at least) what it does.

In short, **what does using `CALLBACK` do for me**? Is it absolutely required, or can I leave that declaration off?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is required, __stdcall is not the default calling convention on most compilers.  __cdecl is the normal default.  Having the calling convention wrong will make your program misbehave in a hard to diagnose way.  The argument values are wrong and the stack gets imbalanced.

It is only an issue in 32-bit code, 64-bit code has only one calling convention.  Whomever adds another one is going to be summarily banned to a small island in the South Atlantic for life.  __stdcall is an historic accident that started with the pascal calling convention in DOS and 16-bit Windows, back when shaving an instruction off the call was important when so little memory was available.

Comment: +1 for the South Atlantic island idea. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer.

Comment: To be clear, the Win32 API is what requires __stdcall. Also, the Wikipedia entry on this is worth the read... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Not just the win32 api, any library published by Microsoft uses stdcall.  When they named it "standard call", they really meant it.  Those libraries are meant to be usable from any language runtime, ultimately they can never keep everybody happy.  The compromise tends to be to keep everybody equally unhappy.

Answer (score 2):

`CALLBACK` is not a keyword. It's simply a preprocessor macro that gets replaced with the appropriate calling convention, which as you already noted is `__stdcall`.

This is a "Pascal-like" calling convention that [doesn't support variable number of arguments](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=53), was used by Win32 API from early days, and is still there for historical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`CALLBACK` is defined as `__stdcall` mechanism. But that itself is a function which will be called by some other function on occurance of an event(say).

Is it must? Yes! Why? because the default is `__cdecl`